# C# enforce set of classes to be used together

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

Here is my use case. Say I have a game with two modes: CoolMode and NormalMode.

Both game modes are very different but share three common objects: Input, Score, and Judger. Each mode would have different implementations, but could be called from the main game using the same code.

```
interface Judger{
  Score Judge(Input i);
}
abstract class Score {...}
abstract class Input {...}
```

I wanted to make sure for example, a CoolMode Input would not be passed to a NormalMode Judger. So my first solution was:

```
interface GameMode{}
interface Judger<T> where T:GameMode{
  Score<T> Judge(Input<T> i);
}
abstract class Score<T> where T:GameMode {...}
abstract class Input<T> where T:GameMode {...}

interface NormalMode{}
class NormalJudger:Judger<NormalMode>{
  Score<NormalMode> Judge(Input<NormalMode> i);
}
class NormalScore:Score<NormalMode>{...}
class NormalInput:NormalInput<NormalMode>{...}

...
```

The problem is that now NormalJudger can take any Input, not just NormalInput.

How can I force (at compile time) the classes {NormalJudger, NormalScore, NormalInput} to be used with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that now NormalJudger can take any Input, not just NormalInput.

If by this you mean that someone could create their own implementation of `Input<NormalMode>` and pass that to `NormalJudger`, then really, you should design `NormalJudger` so that it can judge any kind of `Input<NormalMode>`. Isn't that why you have created `Input` as an abstract class? This is the whole point of abstraction. `Judge` should not care about what specific kind of `Input` it is, as long as it is an `Input<NormalMode>`. It seems like the `NormalMode` type is just a "marker" for the type system to tell your types apart. Well, how about making it actually contain some data/logic, and make `Judge` operate on it?

---

Or, you can just go the quick and dirty way, and parameterise the `Judge` type differently. Rather than parameterise on the mode, parameterise on `Score` and `Input`:

```
public interface Judger<TScore, TInput> 
    where TScore: Score
    where TInput: Input{
  TScore Judge(TInput i);
}
public abstract class Score {}
public abstract class Input {}

interface NormalMode : GameMode {}
class NormalJudger:Judger<NormalScore, NormalInput>{
  public NormalScore Judge(NormalInput i) {return null;}
}
class NormalScore:Score{}
class NormalInput:Input{}
```